# Simplest way to return the value only of a location from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is a very simple question but I always found myself doing too many operation to get a single location value from a dataframe. let me explain:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip('abcde', 'rithf')), columns=['a', 'b'])
df
Out[23]: 
   a  b
0  a  r
1  b  i
2  c  t
3  d  h
4  e  f
```

I am trying to extract the column b value where `column a == a`. using .loc which is very straight forward would return this:

```
df.loc[df.a == 'a', 'b']
Out[24]: 
0    r
Name: b, dtype: object
```

getting the value gets very dirty:

```
df.loc[df.a == 'a', 'b'].values[0]
Out[26]: 
'r'
```

when you know the exact index, it actually returns the value only:

```
df.loc[0, 'b']
Out[27]: 
'r'
```

but obviously I need an indexer first.

so the question is, is there any sexier way `df.loc[df.a == 'a', 'b'].values[0]` to return the actual value only and not aseries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Series.item](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html):

```
print(df.loc[df.a == 'a', 'b'].item())
r
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `argmax` to get the match as a scalar and then use `.loc` -

```
df.loc[(df.a=='a').argmax(),'b']
```

Of course, it assumes that we have a match in that `'a'` column.

Sample run -

```
In [346]: df
Out[346]: 
   a  b
0  a  r
1  b  i
2  c  t
3  d  h
4  e  f

In [347]: (df.a=='a').argmax() # row indexer
Out[347]: 0

In [348]: df.loc[(df.a=='a').argmax(),'b']
Out[348]: 'r'
```

Comment: Thanks @Divakar, it's a bite hackish but does work fine